# Regex: Find tagged strings in text

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I got the following query string that contains a couple tagged values (`key: value` pairs) always at the end of a string:

```
Lorem ipsum age:85 date:15.05.2015 sender: user: John Doe
```

The "Lorem ipsum" is a string that should be ignored as it's not a pair.
The following pairs are valid:

- `age` with `85`
- `date` with `15.05.2015`
- `user` with `John Doe`

A tag should be ignored if no contents can be found after the colon.
Their content can also include spaces up to the next tag's key.

Here's what I got so far:

```
/([\w-]+):\s*(.+?)(?!\s+[\w-]+:)?/g
```

but for some reason it only seems to match the first character of the value and also cut into the "user" tag ([regexr playground](https://regexr.com/4slkb)):

```
age:8
date:1
sender: u
ser:J
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(\w[\w-]*):(?!\s+\w[\w-]*:|\s*$)\s*(.*?)(?=\s+\w[\w-]*:|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YByJca/3)

**Details**

- `(\w[\w-]*)` - Capturing group 1: a word char followed with 0+ word or hyphen chars
- `:` - a colon
- `(?!\s+\w[\w-]*:|\s*$)` - the negative lookahead fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is 1+ whitespaces, a word char followed with 0+ word or hyphen chars and then `:` or 0+ whitespaces at the end of the string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the closest...
- `(?=\s+\w[\w-]*:|$)` - 1+ whitespaces, a word char followed with 0+ word  or hyphen chars and then `:` or just the end of the string.

Comment: [See your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/YByJca/4) to better understand why it fails.  Notice that your regex pattern picks up normal text.  In fact, there is no way for regex alone to "know" where a multi-word value begins and ends, this is why in JSON such values must be in double quotes.

Comment: In this case "John Doe ipsum" would still be assumed as "correct" as all tags are placed at the end of the string. if not, then it's part of the last tag's value and simply a user error. (Surrounding them with quotes may be the wiser option, but has been decided against in this case...)

Answer (score 1):

I seem to get good mileage from the following pattern:

```
(?<!\S)\S+:\s*\S*[^:\s](?!\S)
```

### Demo

The strategy here is to match a key followed by colon, which is then followed by optional whitespace and a term which does *not* also end in colon (to prevent spilling over to another key).  Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
(?<!\S)   assert that what precedes the start of the key is either whitespace
          or the start of the string
\S+       match one or more non whitespace characters (the key)
:         followed by :
\s*       followed by optional whitespace
\S*       a value, zero or more non whitespace characters
[^:\s]    ending in a non colon
(?!\S)    assert that what follows is either whitespace or the end of the string
```

Comment: You get `user` as `John`, but `John Doe` is expected.

Comment: Negative lookbehind makes it less usable, also it doesnt match "Doe" like the other answer, ~~not that it was stated as requirement,~~ i like both answers.

Comment: @Fixation It *is* a requirement to match `John Doe`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Then the OP's data is the problem.  We have no way of actually knowing that `Doe` is part of the key.  If you look closely, you will see the leading content `Lorem ipsum`.

Comment: That is a key, OP has a `[\w-]+` pattern to identify it, the value can contain any char.

Comment: Can confirm, that John Doe is the requirement here. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Your data has a problem, and both answers may likely break in production.